# WhatsApp crashes just after launching without any error messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, 5.1-lollipop, crashes

I have updated my WhatsApp to the latest version (2.18.46) but it crashes as soon as I open it. I don't get any "WhatsApp has stopped working" messages.

Here's what happens:

1. I click the icon
2. White screen opens, notification bar turns WhatsApp green
3. White screen suddenly disappears and I am left with the previous screen

I don't think an instance of WhatsApp is running as I don't get any notifications also. All the messages remain undelivered.

Things I have done:

1. Restarted the phone
2. Checked network - both WiFi, 3G
3. Removed battery, inserted it again, charged till 100%
4. Force killed WhatsApp
5. Uninstall - reinstall WhatsApp

I don't know what's happening. My OS is Lollipop (5.1) Cyanogen. Everything was working fine. It messed up after the update.

Comment: See if you have disabled important permissions in cyanogen settings?

Comment: See if you have disabled google play services or other background data or sync settings?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it has started working. Here's what I did.

1. Remove WhatsApp or any app that crashes
2. Restart the phone [this will remove any instance, cached process, etc.]
3. Remove Play Services [restart the phone]
4. Now the phone should try to update Play Services [you can manually do it by typing Play Services on Play store]
5. Restart the phone
6. Install WhatsApp or any app. Ta-Da! It works.